# how to use keypress events in mvvmcross for android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

i have some problems trying to get the keyboard typing event ...so what i want is 
execute the command "GoContratoCommand" when the user press the "enter" button on the keyboard

this is part of  my ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MultiPage.Core.Services;
 namespace MultiPage.Core.ViewModels
 {
 public class FirstViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
     {



    private Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand _goContratoCommand;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand GoContratoCommand
    {
        get{

                _goContratoCommand = _goContratoCommand ?? new Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand(inv_prod_pareja);
                     return _goContratoCommand;
               }

        }


    }
    }
```

and this is my activity(or view as you want to call it) on the path: views/FirstView.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;

namespace MultiPage.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "View for FirstViewModel")]
    public class FirstView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.screen01);
            var contrato= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtMembershipNumber);
            contrato.EditorAction += EventHandlerContrato;
        }
        public void EventHandlerContrato(object MyObject,EditText.EditorActionEventArgs e){
            e.Handled = false;
            if (e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.ImeNull ||
                e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next ||
                e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Unspecified ||
                e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.None ||
                e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Send ||
                e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Go)
            {
                var algo=((Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel)this.DataContext).GoContratoCommand;
                e.Handled = true;

            }
        }
    }


    }
```

i'm stack on this , can you help me to find out how i can run this command?, or if you know 
another way to use keypress events to call commands i will be grateful if you tell me about it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `Execute` on the Command:

```
          var algo=((Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel)this.DataContext).GoContratoCommand;
          algo.Execute(null);
```

---

For reuse, you could also put this code into a helper class:

```
 public class MyEditText : EditText
 {
     public MyEditText(Context c, IAttributeSet a) : base(c,a) {
        this.EditorAction += EventHandlerContrato;
     }

     public ICommand KeyCommand { get;set; }

     public void EventHandlerContrato(object MyObject,EditText.EditorActionEventArgs e){
        e.Handled = false;
        if (e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.ImeNull ||
            e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next ||
            e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Unspecified ||
            e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.None ||
            e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Send ||
            e.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Go)
        {
            if (KeyCommand != null) {
               KeyCommand.Execute(null);
               e.Handled = true;
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

Then this class could be used in your axml as:

```
 <MyEditText
     local:MvxBind="KeyCommand TheCommand; Text TheText" />
```

Comment: jesus!!!, thanks a lot , and thanks for the tip of the KeyCommand I was looking for a way to do that too,thanks man!, i'm  a newbie on this