# Binding Keyword for Key Presses

Tags: android, mvvmcross

In MVVM Cross is there a binding keyword for `KeyPress`?

For example;

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        local:MvxBind="Text Search KeyPress OnKeyPress"
        android:hint="Search Places" />
```

I want to detect when the user presses `Return`/`Enter` so I can navigate to the next ViewModel `SearchViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not. There is no built in way to do that. Look at [the answer from stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228596/2653134) in another thread.

Short answer: Just make your own implementation of EditText and you can make a Command you can bind on.